# How to load content out of pdf file with javascript (cshtml)

Tags: javascript, .net, pdf, model-view-controller, web-applications

i have a webapp where i'd like to import a pdf file and load the content in a textarea when i do that now, my text seems to be in the wrong format.

[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X96Wz.png)

The code I use now:

```
<script>    
function loadFileAsText(){
      var fileToLoad = document.getElementById("fileToLoad").files[0];
      
        var fileReader = new FileReader();
        fileReader.onload = function(fileLoadedEvent){
            var textFromFileLoaded = fileLoadedEvent.target.result;
            document.getElementById("test").value = textFromFileLoaded;
        };
      
        fileReader.readAsText(fileToLoad, "UTF-8");
      
}
```

Comment: A PDF isn't text. It's a binary format.

Comment: And is there any way to convert that to text?